# "Remote" NFC Antenna

Tags: nfc, pcb-antenna

I'm trying to put together a Near Field sensor where the pcb antenna can be remotely installed  (about 2 ft away). I've looked at NXP PNxxx design here ---  http://eng.utah.edu/~mlewis/ref/NFC/AN1445.pdf

However, the designs in this document have their host interface and antennas immediately next to each other on the **same board**. I'm trying to separate the antenna and host interface (PNxxx w/ matching circuit) and connect these via a wire/cable so that I can place the antenna in another location. I was thinking of using two 24 AWG wires as a cable with a simple two-pin interconnect, but I'm worried that this has impedance implications.

Should I use this approach or a coaxial cable instead? Or on the whole is this a bad idea?